# How does Rav Saadia Gaon account for the suffering of children?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, reincarnation, saadya-gaon, suffering, theodicy

I came across [this excerpt from Rav Saadia Gaon on reincarnation](http://www.mesora.org/SaadiaGaon-Reincarnation.htm) (on mesora.org, where they cite it as Saadia Gaon: “The Book of Beliefs and Opinions” “Refutation of Reincarnation” Yale Judaica Series, Vol. I “The Soul” chap. VIII pp 259") and I'm having trouble understanding part of what he's saying. For context, in the excerpt, Rav Saadia Gaon strongly objects to those who consider reincarnation to be an authentic part of Judaism. In it, he identifies one of the arguments made by proponents of belief in reincarnation as being that the suffering of small children is inconceivable given the idea that God is just, unless their soul had sinned in a previous life. (Setting aside how that could actually work, for the purposes of this question.)

Within the excerpt, Rav Saadia Gaon refutes this in two ways, with the first refutation being that people get compensated in the afterlife for suffering in this world. (Again, setting aside whether that would actually make the suffering itself morally justified, for the purposes of this question.) So I understand that part. But then, it's Rav Saadia Gaon's second refutation I'm having trouble making sense of:

> Furthermore we should like to ask [proponents of belief in reincarnation] what they conceive the original status of the soul to be – we mean its status when it is first created. Is it charged by its Master with any obligation to obey Him or not? If they allege that it is not so charged, then there can be no punishments for it either, since it was not charged with any obligations to begin with. If, on the other hand, they acknowledge the imposition of such a charge, in which case obedience and disobedience did not apply before, they thereby admit that God charges His servants with obligations on account of the future and not at all on account of the past. But then they return to our theory and are forced to give up their insistence on the view that man’s suffering in this world is due solely to his conduct in a previous existence.

What is Rav Saadia Gaon getting at with statements about whether a soul initially is charged with obligations, and what is his subsequent reasoning on that? Is he simply suggesting that people are punished for their future crimes? And if so, why bother with that suggestion at all when it wouldn't cover all circumstances (in particular, small children who suffer and do not survive long enough to sin), when his earlier suggestion (that compensation in the afterlife makes it justifiable to cause children to suffer) would apply to more circumstances?

My best attempt at understanding what he said is that the only way a soul could be subject to punishment for sins is if at one point an obligation is imposed on the soul for the future, and if an obligation can be made now for future actions, then God interacts with the soul at one point based on something in the future, so we should just say that it can also be punished at one point based on future actions. Is that what he's saying, did I miss part of the reasoning, or am I totally off the mark?

Comment: Wish someone would answer your question.

Comment: @Shmuel Well it was only viewed 207 times, maybe none of those were by someone who is really familiar with Rav Saadia Gaon's philosophy. Re-reading the quotation now, maybe he is saying that if they believe even first-incarnations are subject to punishment, then there is no need for reincarnation? But I feel like I'm unable to come up with an explanation for the quotation that makes sense and is a good rebuttal, which leads me to think that either Rav Saadia Gaon used poor reasoning, that he was a poor communicator in this instance, or that it is a poor translation.

Comment: E.g. the broader quote says, "This view [about reincarnation explaining children suffering] is, however, subject to numerous refutations." And then he proceeds to give only two reasons, which is a far cry from "numerous." Something is missing here.

Comment: Rav Saadia Gaon says that children suffering unjustly will be compensated in heaven is one refutation. This is not satisfactory to some and they came up with the answer that they are suffering due to sins committed in a previous life. This makes sense to many people. I think we simply do not know and will never know. All we can do is try to be the best we can be and help others to do so as well.